# Going through several links while scaping web pabe

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to make my web scraper go through several links before actually scraping the website and i can't seem to find how to make it work.

The website i'm trying to scrape is amazon.

Let's say i start from https://www.amazon.com/ (That being my 'start_url').
Once i'm there, i want to search something in the amazon search bar, for example, "Laptops" and go through search.

How can this be done? I can extract data if i force the start url (For example, the url for searching laptops: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Laptop)
 but i cant seem to be able to obtain that URL while starting from the amazon home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several requests to search, maybe it is better to call them in another way:

```
search_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords={}'

def start_requests(self):
    keywords = ['laptop', 'something other']
    for keyword in keywords:
        yield Request(self.search_url.format(keyword))

def parse(self, response) 
    # parse your pages here
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the help!